# How to find my php.ini in my webhost?

Tags: php, apache, web-services, runtime-error, ini

I'm having an error log that says:

```
Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini.
```

I want to change the settings on my php.ini on my webhost but i cant find it.

Comment: `phpinfo()`'s output tells you which files were used, and where they are.

Comment: You probably don't have direct access to your PHP.INI file on a web host. You have to configure this stuff through cPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a shared hosting, it's most likely that you do not have access to the php.ini

However, you can change the desired value by adding this to your .htaccess:

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000 //you can change 3000 to whatever suits your needs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have have php.ini access add these to your .htaccess

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 3000
```