# having issue in htaccess HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, web-services, .htaccess, runtime-error

I got that error after editing my .htaccess in my webhost with this values:

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 3000
```

How to fix it? i need to put those line of code in my htacess cause i got an error that says

```
Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini.
```

in my page.

Comment: How do you know your host is running suhosin

Comment: Why can't you modify them in your php.ini as it states?

Comment: Almost a dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553203/how-to-find-my-php-ini-in-my-webhost). If you get a 500 with those options, then it's likely your host has disable php overrides at the htaccess level as well. Which means you have **NO** way to making these changes. You cannot use ini_set() for them, because by the time the ini_set() would get executed, PHP will already have aborted due to excessive input variables anyways.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy idk i found that line of code in google after searching for solution. How to know then?

Comment: Pretty simple, buddy. `if(extension_loaded('suhosin')){ echo 'Suhosin is loaded!'}else{ echo 'Suhosin is not loaded!'}`. Put this in a php file and execute it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy if my host doesnt run suhosin what should i put to my htaccess?

Comment: Just tell us who your host is, and we'll tell you if you can even modify the max input vars value.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy im using http://www.web.com.ph/ as webhost

Comment: I contacted your host personally and they've advised you can modify this value within the php.ini. If it doesn't work, they've requested you contact them directly and they'll give you the support you need, or help you modify this setting at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file. This code works for me. If you want to add more menu tabs ? then increase the value more than 5000.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>

 php_value max_input_vars 5000

</IfModule>
```